# Is the resulting $3$-digit number divisible by $3$?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

From the 2012 Australian Mathematical Competition (Junior Level):

> How many four-digit numbers containing no zeros have the property that whenever any its four digits is removed, the resulting three-digit number is divisible by $3$?

To solve this problem, I listed 4 cases

1. If the 1st digit is deleted then the remaining number would have to be a multiple of $3$. That means that there are $10 \cdot 10 \cdot 3 = 300$ cases.
2. If the 2nd digit is deleted then the remaining number would have to be a multiple of $3$. That means that there are $10 \cdot 10 \cdot 3 = 300$ cases.
3. If the 3rd digit is deleted then the remaining number would have to be a multiple of $3$. That means that there are $10 \cdot 10 \cdot 3 = 300$ cases.
4. If the 4th digit is deleted then the remaining number would have to be a multiple of $3$. That means that there are $10 \cdot 10 \cdot 3 = 300$ cases.

So there are $1200$ cases but this is wrong.

Comment: You include for example 1234 in the count of the first set because it is a multiple of 3 when the first digit is removed. It does not have the property that you can remove any other digit and have it be divisible by 3.

Comment: All 4 digits must have the same value when considered modulo 3,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number is divisible by 3 iff its sum of digits is divisible by 3. Using this fact, it is easy to see that our 4-digit number satisfies the given condition iff the four digits all have the same remainder modulo 3. Therefore, we have $3*(9/3)^4=243$ cases when each digit is nonzero.

Comment: Great answer! Just something to clarify. Why is the equation you added $3∗(9/3)^4=243$ and how did you figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanXu The $(9/3)^4=81$ part refers to four numbers with each say $\equiv 0 \mod 3$. The tripling then accounts for numbers with $\equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $\equiv 2\mod 3$. Example for the latter: 5555, which always yields 555 (div. by 3), but 5 $\equiv 2 \mod 3$.

Comment: Thanks, @Piita. I discussed exactly in that way.

Comment: @Ayaka Sure! Feel free to copypaste / paraphrase this into an edit, will then delete comment